# Liferay - Set Expando Field Value in a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay, expando

I need to set a User Expando field value in a Javascript Function in liferay. It is possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the json api like this way

```
Liferay.Service(
  '/expandovalue/add-value',
  {
    companyId: 20154,
    className: 'com.liferay.portal.model.User',
    tableName: 'CUSTOM_FIELDS',
    columnName: 'test',
    classPK: 30924,
    data: 'test'
  },
  function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
);
```

where

**columnName** is the name of your custom field

**classPK** is the entity id in this case userId

**data** the value of the custom field

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful.

Comment: I'm new with JSON API. I used  
`classPK : <%=selUser.getUserId() %>,`  to retrieve user id, and  
`data : A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>userAdminId').get('value')`  
to set data. But the value is a String, and the type of expando is a long. It is possible to cast the value or i must to change the type of expando field?

Comment: just add user.getUserId()+'' this with trasform it to string but i think is better to transform the type of exapando to long